# The exception of excess scrolling listview in samsung galaxy

Tags: events, listview, scroll, galaxy

Since the listview in samsung galaxy tab can respond to excess scroll event, and due to some of my special operation (delete the backend datasource for the listview), so that when the galaxy handle the excess scroll message, it throw a runtime exception, that can be found below. 
I want to make the listview in samsung galaxy  not respond the excess scroll event. 
Can someone tell me how I can set the listview to meet this requirement?

The exception I got:

```
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 12, size is 1
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.isEnabled(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:164)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDrawWithExcessScroll_Default(ListView.java:3352)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3093)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6796)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2545)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6796)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6796)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2078)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1433)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1175)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1753)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4632)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
10-09 09:02:26.758: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1845):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```